# How to customise flask return script tag alert function

Tags: javascript, python, flask

How can customise the return script tag alert function in python flask

```
return '<script>alert("notification deleted");window.location="/View_Notification"</script>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do I get you right, that you want to customize the look for the alert("whatever")?

If so, that's not a flask specific task. If you are using a CSS framework, like bulma for example, you can use they're so called modals (https://bulma.io/documentation/components/modal/) and make them visible/invisble instead of popping the plain javascript alert.

Chances are that I didn't understand your question tho.